# Python multiprocessing: Parallel Pipeline implementation

Tags: python, performance, subprocess, pipeline, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to create a pipeline but I have bad exit issues(zombies) and performance ones. I have created this generic class:

```
class Generator(Process):
'''
<function>: function to call. None value means that the current class will
    be used as a template for another class, with <function> being defined
    there
<input_queues> : Queue or list of Queue objects , which refer to the input
    to <function>.
<output_queues> : Queue or list of Queue objects , which are used to pass
    output
<sema_to_acquire> : Condition or list of Condition objects, which are
    blocking generation while not notified
<sema_to_release> : Condition or list of Condition objects, which will be
    notified after <function> is called
'''

def __init__(self, function=None, input_queues=None, output_queues=None, sema_to_acquire=None,
             sema_to_release=None):
    Process.__init__(self)
    self.input_queues = input_queues
    self.output_queues = output_queues
    self.sema_to_acquire = sema_to_acquire
    self.sema_to_release = sema_to_release
    if function is not None:
            self.function = function

def run(self):
    if self.sema_to_release is not None:
            try:
                self.sema_to_release.release()
            except AttributeError:
                [sema.release() for sema in self.sema_to_release]

    while True:
        if self.sema_to_acquire is not None:
            try:
                self.sema_to_acquire.acquire()
            except AttributeError:
                [sema.acquire() for sema in self.sema_to_acquire]


        if self.input_queues is not None:
            try:
                data = self.input_queues.get()
            except AttributeError:
                data = [queue.get() for queue in self.input_queues]
            isiterable = True
            try:
                iter(data)
                res = self.function(*tuple(data))
            except TypeError, te:
                res = self.function(data)
        else:
            res = self.function()
        if self.output_queues is not None:
            try:
                if self.output_queues.full():
                    self.output_queues.get(res)
                self.output_queues.put(res)
            except AttributeError:
                [queue.put(res) for queue in self.output_queues]
        if self.sema_to_release is not None:
            if self.sema_to_release is not None:
                try:
                    self.sema_to_release.release()
                except AttributeError:
                    [sema.release() for sema in self.sema_to_release]
```

to simulate a worker inside a pipeline. The Generator is wanted to run an infinite while loop, in which a function is executed using input from n queues and the result is written to m queues. There are some semaphores which need to be acquired by a process, before one iteration happens, and when the iteration finishes some other semaphores are released. So, for processes needed to run on parallel and produce an input for another I send 'crossed' semaphores as arguments, in order to force them to perform together single iterations. For processes which do not need to run on parallel I do not use any conditions. An example (which I actually use, if anyone ignores the input functions) is the following:

```
import time
from multiprocess import Lock
print_lock = Lock()
_t_=0.5
def func0(data):
    time.sleep(_t_)
    print_lock.acquire()
    print 'func0 sends',data
    print_lock.release()
    return data
def func1(data):
    time.sleep(_t_)
    print_lock.acquire()
    print 'func1 receives and sends',data
    print_lock.release()
    return data
def func2(data):
    time.sleep(_t_)
    print_lock.acquire()
    print 'func2 receives and sends',data
    print_lock.release()
    return data
def func3(*data):
    print_lock.acquire()
    print 'func3 receives',data
    print_lock.release()


run_svm = Semaphore()
run_rf = Semaphore()
inp_rf = Queue()
inp_svm = Queue()
out_rf = Queue()
out_svm = Queue()
kin_stream = Queue()
res_mixed = Queue()
streamproc = Generator(func0,
                       input_queues=kin_stream,
                       output_queues=[inp_rf,
                                       inp_svm])
streamproc.daemon = True
streamproc.start()
svm_class = Generator(func1,
                       input_queues=inp_svm,
                       output_queues=out_svm,
                       sema_to_acquire=run_svm,
                       sema_to_release=run_rf)
svm_class.daemon=True
svm_class.start()
rf_class = Generator(func2,
                      input_queues=inp_rf,
                      output_queues=out_rf,
                      sema_to_acquire=run_rf,
                      sema_to_release=run_svm)
rf_class.daemon=True
rf_class.start()
mixed_class = Generator(func3,
                         input_queues=[out_rf, out_svm])
mixed_class.daemon = True
mixed_class.start()
count = 1
while True:
    kin_stream.put([count])
    count+=1
    time.sleep(1)
streamproc.join()
svm_class.join()
rf_class.join()
mixed_class.join()
```

This example gives:

```
func0 sends 1
func2 receives and sends 1
func1 receives and sends 1
func3 receives (1, 1)
func0 sends 2
func2 receives and sends 2
func1 receives and sends 2
func3 receives (2, 2)
func0 sends 3
func2 receives and sends 3
func1 receives and sends 3
func3 receives (3, 3)
...
```

All good. **However**, if I try to kill main then the other subprocesses are not guaranteed to terminate: the terminal might freeze, or the python compiler might remain running on the background (probably zombies) and I have no clue why this is happening, as I have set the corresponding daemons to True. 
Does anyone have a better idea of implementing this type of pipeline or can suggest a solution to this evil problem? Thank you all.

## EDIT

Fixed testing. The zombies still **do exist** however.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this problem, by introducing a termination queue as additional argument to the given class and set up a signal handler for SIGINT interrupt, in order to stop the pipeline execution. I do not know if this is the most elegant way to get it working, but it works. Also, the way the signal handler is set is important, as it must be set before process.start() for some reason, if anyone knows why, he can comment. Furthermore the signal handler is inherited by the subprocesses, so I have to put the `join` inside a `try:..except AssertionError:pass` pattern, otherwise it will throw error (again, if someone knows how to bypass this, please elaborate). Anyways, it works.

### SOURCE CODE

```
class Generator(Process):
    '''
    <term_queue>: Queue to write termination events, must be same for all
                processes spawned
    <function>: function to call. None value means that the current class will
        be used as a template for another class, with <function> being defined
        there
    <input_queues> : Queue or list of Queue objects , which refer to the input
        to <function>.
    <output_queues> : Queue or list of Queue objects , which are used to pass
        output
    <sema_to_acquire> : Semaphore or list of Semaphore objects, which are
        blocking function execution
    <sema_to_release> : Semaphore or list of Semaphore objects, which will be
        released after <function> is called
    '''

    def __init__(self, term_queue,
                 function=None, input_queues=None, output_queues=None, sema_to_acquire=None,
                 sema_to_release=None):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.term_queue = term_queue
        self.input_queues = input_queues
        self.output_queues = output_queues
        self.sema_to_acquire = sema_to_acquire
        self.sema_to_release = sema_to_release
        if function is not None:
            self.function = function

    def run(self):
        if self.sema_to_release is not None:
            try:
                self.sema_to_release.release()
            except AttributeError:
                deb = [sema.release() for sema in self.sema_to_release]
        while True:
            if not self.term_queue.empty():
                self.term_queue.put((self.name, 0))
                break
            try:
                if self.sema_to_acquire is not None:
                    try:
                        self.sema_to_acquire.acquire()
                    except AttributeError:
                        deb = [sema.acquire() for sema in self.sema_to_acquire]

                if self.input_queues is not None:
                    try:
                        data = self.input_queues.get()
                    except AttributeError:
                        data = tuple([queue.get()
                                      for queue in self.input_queues])
                    res = self.function(data)
                else:
                    res = self.function()
                if self.output_queues is not None:
                    try:
                        if self.output_queues.full():
                            self.output_queues.get(res)
                        self.output_queues.put(res)
                    except AttributeError:
                        deb = [queue.put(res) for queue in self.output_queues]
                if self.sema_to_release is not None:
                    if self.sema_to_release is not None:
                        try:
                            self.sema_to_release.release()
                        except AttributeError:
                            deb = [sema.release() for sema in self.sema_to_release]
            except Exception as exc:
                self.term_queue.put((self.name, exc))
                break



def signal_handler(sig, frame, term_queue, processes):
    '''
    <term_queue> is the queue to write termination of the __main__
    <processes> is a dicitonary holding all running processes
    '''
    term_queue.put((__name__, 'SIGINT'))
    try:
        [processes[key].join() for key in processes]
    except AssertionError:
        pass
    sys.exit(0)

term_queue = Queue()
'''
initialize some Generators and add them to <processes> dicitonary
'''
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lambda sig,frame: signal_handler(sig,frame,
                                                              term_queue,processes))
[processes[key].start() for key in processes]
while True:
    if not term_queue.empty():
        [processes[key].join() for key in processes]
        break
```

and the example is changed accordingly (comment if you want me to add it)

Answer (score 0):

I have had to work on this issue as well, and indeed, passing some communication pipe or queue to the processes seems to be the easiest way to tell them to terminate.

However the termination code can take advantage of a `finally:` bloc in the main process, it will take care of any event including signals.

If your processes are supposed to terminate at the same time as an object, you might also want to play with weakref.finalize, but it can be [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49082914/python-weakref-finalize-not-run-if-background-threads-are-alive/49095183#49095183).